# Iphone Custom UITabBarItem without rounded edges

Tags: iphone, objective-c, rounded-corners

i try to customize a uitabbar

i extended uitabbar item and now have a customized image in it but i cant get rid of the rounded edges.

code:

```
@interface CustomTabBarItem : UITabBarItem  
{
    UIImage *customHighlightedImage;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImage *customHighlightedImage;

@end

@implementation CustomTabBarItem

@synthesize customHighlightedImage;

- (void) dealloc
{
    [customHighlightedImage release]; customHighlightedImage=nil;
    [super dealloc];
}

-(UIImage *) selectedImage
{
    return self.customHighlightedImage;
}

@end
```

maybe somoen knows how to get rid of the rounded rect

around the image

thanks in advance
alex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

thanks solved it with custom tab bar items

**NOT APPLE APPROVED YET.**

goes into tabController1.m

```
    - (id) init
{   
    if(self = [super init])
    {
        CustomTabBarItem *tabItem = [[CustomTabBarItem alloc]
                                     initWithTitle:@"" image:nil tag:0];

        tabItem.customHighlightedImage=[UIImage imageNamed:TABBAR_TAB_4_ACTIVE];
        tabItem.customStdImage=[UIImage imageNamed:TABBAR_TAB_4_DEFAULT];       

        self.tabBarItem=tabItem;
        [tabItem release]; 
        tabItem=nil;    
    }
    return self;
}
```

cutom tabbaritem:

```
@interface CustomTabBarItem : UITabBarItem  
{
    UIImage *customHighlightedImage;
    UIImage *customStdImage;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImage *customHighlightedImage;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImage *customStdImage;

@end

#import "CustomTabBarItem.h"


@implementation CustomTabBarItem

@synthesize customHighlightedImage;
@synthesize customStdImage;

- (void) dealloc
{
    [customHighlightedImage release]; customHighlightedImage=nil;
    [customStdImage release]; customStdImage=nil;   
    [super dealloc];
}

-(UIImage *) selectedImage
{
    return self.customHighlightedImage;
}

-(UIImage *) unselectedImage
{
    return self.customStdImage;
}

@end
```

Comment: Yes, It was approved. Search for "cinemaxx"

Comment: Alex, How did you get the red / purple background to take up the entire space of the button when active?

Comment: I'm still getting the highlighted area behind my icon, and can't get the whole area to use the background.

Comment: sorry for the delay. i posted it as answer at the bottom

Comment: Thanks ... I've got a CustomUITabBarController and CustomUITabBarItem that I've subclassed and trying to get working ... the only thing left to fix was the highlighting still showed up ... I'll try and use some of the solution below and if I get it working will put it up on Github.

Comment: unselectedImage and selectedImage did not raise any problems with Apple. So weird.

Answer (score 4):

**This is dirty - but works and got approved:**

- resizes tabbar
- use your own images in own size

in the tab controller setup

```
    tabController   = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
tabController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 72, 320, 480 - (82));
tabController.delegate = self;
UIImageView *bgImageView;
bgImageView = [ [ UIImageView alloc ] initWithImage: [UIImage imageNamed:TABBAR_BACKGROUND]];
bgImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, -11, 320, 60);

[[tabController tabBar] addSubview:bgImageView];
[[tabController tabBar] sendSubviewToBack:bgImageView];
tabController.tabBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 460 - (59 + 52 - 11), 320, 49);
[bgImageView release];

[window addSubview:tabController.view];
```

in the tabviewcontroller1 init method

```
   - (id) init
{
    if(self = [super init])
    {       
        CustomTabBarItem *tabItem = [[CustomTabBarItem alloc]
                                     initWithTitle:@"" image:nil tag:0];

        tabItem.customHighlightedImage=[UIImage imageNamed:TABBAR_TAB_1_ACTIVE];
        tabItem.customStdImage=[UIImage imageNamed:TABBAR_TAB_1_DEFAULT];       

        self.tabBarItem=tabItem;
        [tabItem release]; 
        tabItem=nil;
    }

return self;
}
```

and the custom tab bar it looks like

```
    @interface CustomTabBarItem : UITabBarItem  
    {
        UIImage *customHighlightedImage;
        UIImage *customStdImage;
    }

    @property (nonatomic, retain) UIImage *customHighlightedImage;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) UIImage *customStdImage;

    @end

#import "CustomTabBarItem.h"


@implementation CustomTabBarItem

@synthesize customHighlightedImage;
@synthesize customStdImage;

- (void) dealloc
{
    [customHighlightedImage release]; customHighlightedImage=nil;
    [customStdImage release]; customStdImage=nil;   
    [super dealloc];
}

-(UIImage *) selectedImage
{
    return self.customHighlightedImage;
}

-(UIImage *) unselectedImage
{
    return self.customStdImage;
}

@end
```

**IMPORTANT:**

i'm pretty new to iphone development and pretty pretty shure you can do this way less hacky. furthermore i got approved with this which does NOT mean you autmoatically will, too.

Answer (score 1):

Set the `cornerRadius` on the view that has rounded corners to 0:

```
view.layer.cornerRadius = 0;
```

Also, you will probably need to add a #include to get the CALayer declarations:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a query in the above implementation.

As per apple we should not use private / un-documented API's,

In the above code, the two methods

```
-(UIImage *) selectedImage {
    return self.customHighlightedImage; }

-(UIImage *) unselectedImage {
    return self.customStdImage; }
```

These methods were not defined in the custom subclass **CustomTabBarItem**.

These methods are un-documented / hidden methods in **UITabBarItem** class and overridden in the **CustomTabBarItem** class.

Is it fine to over-ride the undocumented methods?

I am still surprised how this got approved by Apple.
I need some clarifications here.

Answer (score 0):

Any other apps validated by Apple with this code ? Very interested to know if we are authorized to use selectedImage and unselectedImage methods ?